# ElasticSearch - leave large text field out of all processes, but still return it in results?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an ElasticSearch index (ES version 6.4.2) which contains 100+ million documents consisting of about 5 fields each.  One of those fields is the full text of a news article.

The issue is that right now, our searches on this index are taking upwards of 5-6 seconds to return results, whereas all of our other indexes (which are typical structured records) take less than a second.  The thing is, we don't need to search inside of the field that contains the news text at query time at all, but we do want to return that field in the results.

What I'm assuming here is that all that news text is in the ES cache and lending to these long search times, when they don't even need to be since we don't search on them.  Is there a way to, for lack of a better way to articulate this, leave the news text field out of all ES processes/caching, but still actually return that field in the results?  I'm trying to test ways to increase the speed of the searches on this index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two approaches to this:

**1.** Set `"index": false` for the field which should not be searchable. Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html).

```
{
  "fNews": {
    "type": "text",
    "index": false
  }
}
```

**2.** If you are using query_string query to search then set the fields on which the search should be performed. Lets assume you have 3 fields `f1`, `f2` and `fNews` and you don't want to search on `fNews` then query would look something like below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "f1",
        "f2"
      ],
      "query": "some search string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Let me know if these helped.

Comment: Hi Nishant - do you know if option 1 can be achieved without a full re-index?

Comment: @Stpete111 No, it requires re-index.